# Do nothing keyword in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a keyword to 'do nothing' in C#?

For example I want to use a ternary operator where one of the actions is to take no action:

```
officeDict.ContainsKey("0") ? DO NOTHING : officeDict.Add("0","")
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if`?

Comment: In your example, you should use an "if" statement instead of a ternary operator.

Comment: ternary operation should have result.

Comment: In your example you actually do not need a ternary operator, an `IF` block is enough. In other cases it depends.

Comment: I cant help but feel like im getting trolled on this question. =p

Comment: This question was closed as "not a real question". It may not be a great question, yet it seems to be a real question since it was asked again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146905/do-nothing-when-other-side-of-ternary-operator-is-reached/41146937#41146937

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, there is no such keyword. Besides, the `?:` operator is not meant for deciding *actions*. It's meant for deciding *values* (or, more technically, *value expressions*).

You really, really want to use an if condition for this sort of decision-making instead:

```
if (!officeDict.ContainsKey("0"))
    officeDict.Add("0", "");
```

Answer (score 22):

As others have pointed out, using an `if` statement is far more idiomatic here.

But to answer what you ask, you can use lambdas and delegates:

```
// Bad code, do not use:
(officeDict.ContainsKey("0") ? (Action)(() => { }) : () => officeDict.Add("0", ""))();
```

Comment: Credit for actually providing a working solution. Even if it is friggin retarded...

Answer (score 7):

Setting aside the fact that this is a bad idea, you actually can create a 'DoNothing' method using an attribute to conditionally emit the method call (note this relies on the convention that you don't #define a 'NEVER' condition.)  Because of the ConditionalAttribute, calls to the method will not be emitted and you essentially have a 'nop' section of code.

```
       [Conditional("NEVER")] 
       public void DoNothing() 
       { 
       }
```

Still, as several others have already pointed out, this is not recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to use a ternary operator, if you only want to do something in one of the cases ?
Why don't you just invert the condition and use an if statement ?

```
if (!officeDict.ContainsKey("0"))
{
    officeDict.Add("0","")
}
```

Comment: Good advice: Don't write spaces before question marks, it looks unprofessional.

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator is for *expressions*, not statements.

You want an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use an if statement so the code looks like this:

```
if(!officeDict.ContainsKey("0"))
    officeDict.Add("0","")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not write it with a simple `if`?

```
if (!officeDict.ContainsKey("0"))
    officeDict.Add("0","")
```

It will be far more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use an IF statement for this?

```
if(!officeDict.ContainsKey("0")) officeDict.Add("0","");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an if statement instead.

```
if (!officeDict.ContainsKey("0")) 
{
    officeDict.Add("0","")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this (grinns)

```
    if (officeDict.ContainsKey("0")) 
       Thread.Sleep(1) 
   else
       officeDict.Add("0","")
```