# Perform action based on if statement using lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

How to write a fancy if statement in one line using lambda?

I want to have something like this:

```
this.SomeBoolValue == false ? (() => MessageBox.Show("False!")) : (() => MessageBox.Show("True!"));
```

Thanks

Comment: Obvious question time: why?

Comment: out of curiosity, plus to have a fancy code.

Comment: Follow up question: why lambda, there is no need here at all?

Comment: can do it without lambda, more curios about one line if statement.

Comment: Where 'fancy' means 'hard to understand and maintain'.

Comment: Can still do an `if` on a single line, but it's harder to read.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12957197/412770

Comment: @Ani - it looks like answer you've found solves exactly the same issue - closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's really stupid and you should not do that!** But for teaching purposes, here's code that does what you want.

```
(this.SomeBoolValue == false
    ? (Action)(() => MessageBox.Show("False!"))
    : (Action)(() => MessageBox.Show("True!")))();
```

1. You need to cast your lambda to some delegate type (here it's `Action`), because lambda expressions are typeless by default - they are typed according to the context.
2. You need to actually call the lambda, that's why there is `()` at the end.

Comment: Dunno why someone is downvoting, this is correct. Anyway, I'll give you a +1

Answer (score 0):

Some 'single line' variants without using lambda that all achieve the same thing:

```
if(this.SomeBoolValue == false) MessageBox.Show("False!"); else MessageBox.Show("True!");

MessageBox.Show(this.SomeBoolValue ? "True!" : "False!");

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}!", this.SomeBoolValue));
```